# How to run QGIS 3 processing tool (DISSOLVE) in c++

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, c++

For my QGIS C++ Plugin I have to run the **QgsDissolveAlgorithm**- processing tool.

I have found an example, how to do that in python:

```py
import processing
    
infn = "path/to/dissolve"
outfn2 = "output/path/value/dissolve"
    
#dissolve features based on values in an attribute table field
processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':infn, FIELD':['GRID_CODE'], 'OUTPUT':outfn2})
```

I searched in QGIS sources and on github but found no example, how to do that in c++.

Has anybody an idea?

**EDIT:**

I tried J.Monticolo's hint and tried something like this:

```
QgsDissolveAlgorithm* algDissolve= new QgsDissolveAlgorithm();
    QVariantMap params = QVariantMap();
    params.insert("FIELD", QObject::tr("['KGN']"));
    params.insert("INPUT", QObject::tr("C:/temp/kreise.shp"));
    params.insert("OUTPUT", QObject::tr("C:/temp/dissolve.shp"));
    QgsProcessingContext context = QgsProcessingContext();
    QgsProcessingFeedback* feedback = new QgsProcessingFeedback();
    QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask task = QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(algDissolve, params, context, feedback);
```

But now I get a linker error, I think because of the virtual function.

```
error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual void __cdecl QgsDissolveAlgorithm::initAlgorithm(class QMap<class QString,class QVariant> const &)" (?initAlgorithm@QgsDissolveAlgorithm@@UEAAXAEBV?$QMap@VQString@@VQVariant@@@@@Z)".
```

Comment: IMHO, it's somewhere here : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/processing/qgsprocessingalgorithm.h to create a processing and here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/processing/qgsprocessingalgrunnertask.cpp to run it, but can't confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long hairy searching in QGIS sources found out, the algorithm has to be created from QGIS Application Processing Registry. Then you can run it with a set of input parameters. As result of this function you get the layername. If it is a layer created in the temporary layer store you can grab it with help of QgsProcessingContext.

```
QgsProcessingRegistry* reg = QgsApplication::processingRegistry();
QgsProcessingAlgorithm* algDissolve = reg->createAlgorithmById("native:dissolve");

QVariantMap params = QVariantMap();
params.insert("FIELD", QObject::tr("['KGN']"));
params.insert("INPUT", QObject::tr("C:/temp/kreise.shp"));
//params.insert("OUTPUT", QObject::tr("C:/temp/dissolve.shp"));
params.insert("OUTPUT", QObject::tr("TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"));
QgsProcessingContext context = QgsProcessingContext();
QgsProcessingFeedback* feedback = new QgsProcessingFeedback();

bool ok = false;
QVariantMap result = algDissolve->run(params, context, feedback, &ok);
if (ok) {
  QString layerId = result.value("OUTPUT").toString();
  qDebug() << layerId;
  QgsMapLayer* lyr = context.getMapLayer(layerId);
}
```